# What does this error mean? And how can I fix it?

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, autoencoder

I'm using TensorFlow to create an autoencoder model, but I am facing an error and I don't know what it means nor how to fix it. The only clue that I get from this error message is that there are incompatible shapes "[32,14110,32] vs. [25,14110,32]". Where is that coming from given that I'm using the same variable/data as my input and target variable because I'm training the data using an autoencoder model. I inputted data with the shape (2425, 28220) after splitting it into testing, training, and validation. I figured it might be pointless to split the data to have a testing set simply because I'm training the model using the same data as input and output. I don't know let me know what you all thoughts are. Again, I'm new to machine learning and tensorflow, so try to bear with me. Here is my code:

```
from __future__ import absolute_import
from __future__ import division
from __future__ import print_function

import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

from tensorflow.keras.models import Model
from tensorflow.keras import datasets, layers, models


from tensorflow_privacy.privacy.analysis import compute_dp_sgd_privacy
from tensorflow_privacy.privacy.optimizers.dp_optimizer import DPGradientDescentGaussianOptimizer
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.preprocessing import MinMaxScaler



genotype_file = 'genotype_full_1_2.txt'
phenotype_file = 'phenotype.csv'


genotype_data = pd.read_csv(genotype_file, sep='\t', index_col=0)


#default values
dropout_percentage = .25
max_epochs = 1000
min_epochs = 2
batch_size = 32
convfilter_size = 5
maxpooling_filtersize = 2
upsampling_filtersize = 2
numb_kernels = 32


training_percentage = .65
validation_percentage = .15
testing_percentage = .20



scaler = MinMaxScaler() 
genotypedata_scaled = scaler.fit_transform(genotype_data.dropna())



#splitting the data
train_data, testing_data = train_test_split(genotypedata_scaled, test_size=testing_percentage, train_size=training_percentage)
train_data, valid_data = train_test_split(train_data, train_size=1-validation_percentage)


#creating autoencoder(based on SCDA model)
#///////////////////////////////ENCODER
model = models.Sequential()
model.add(layers.InputLayer(input_shape=(genotype_data.shape[1],1), batch_size=batch_size))
model.add(layers.Conv1D(filters=numb_kernels, kernel_size=convfilter_size * 2, strides=1, padding='same', activation='relu'))#CONV1D
model.add(layers.MaxPooling1D(pool_size=maxpooling_filtersize))#MAXPOOLING
model.add(layers.Dropout(dropout_percentage))#DROPOUT
model.add(layers.Conv1D(filters=numb_kernels * 2, kernel_size=convfilter_size, strides=1, padding='same', activation='relu'))#CONV1D
model.add(layers.MaxPooling1D(pool_size=maxpooling_filtersize))#MAXPOOLING
model.add(layers.Dropout(dropout_percentage))#DROPOUT
model.add(layers.Conv1D(filters=numb_kernels * 4, kernel_size=convfilter_size, strides=1, padding='same', activation='relu'))#CONV1D


#///////////////////////////////DECODER
model.add(layers.Conv1D(filters=numb_kernels * 4, kernel_size=convfilter_size, strides=1, padding='same', activation='relu'))#CONV1D
model.add(layers.UpSampling1D(size=upsampling_filtersize))#UPSAMPLING ***CHECK
model.add(layers.Dropout(dropout_percentage))#DROPOUT
model.add(layers.Conv1D(filters=numb_kernels * 2, kernel_size=convfilter_size, strides=1, padding='same', activation='relu'))#CONV1D
model.add(layers.UpSampling1D(size=upsampling_filtersize))#UPSAMPLING ***CHECK
model.add(layers.Dropout(dropout_percentage))#DROPOUT
model.add(layers.Conv1D(filters=1, kernel_size=convfilter_size, strides=1, padding='same', activation='relu'))#CONV1D



#summary of model
model.compile(loss='mse', optimizer='adam', metrics=['mse'])
model.summary()

#training the model
scda_train = model.fit(train_data, train_data, batch_size=batch_size,epochs=1,verbose=1, validation_data=(valid_data, valid_data))
```

Here is the summary of my autoencoder model:

```
Model: "sequential_2"
_________________________________________________________________
 Layer (type)                Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
 conv1d_12 (Conv1D)          (32, 28220, 32)           352       
                                                                 
 max_pooling1d_4 (MaxPooling  (32, 14110, 32)          0         
 1D)                                                             
                                                                 
 dropout_4 (Dropout)         (32, 14110, 32)           0         
                                                                 
 conv1d_13 (Conv1D)          (32, 14110, 64)           10304     
                                                                 
 max_pooling1d_5 (MaxPooling  (32, 7055, 64)           0         
 1D)                                                             
                                                                 
 dropout_5 (Dropout)         (32, 7055, 64)            0         
                                                                 
 conv1d_14 (Conv1D)          (32, 7055, 128)           41088     
                                                                 
 conv1d_15 (Conv1D)          (32, 7055, 128)           82048     
                                                                 
 up_sampling1d_4 (UpSampling  (32, 14110, 128)         0         
 1D)                                                             
                                                                 
 dropout_6 (Dropout)         (32, 14110, 128)          0         
                                                                 
 conv1d_16 (Conv1D)          (32, 14110, 64)           41024     
                                                                 
 up_sampling1d_5 (UpSampling  (32, 28220, 64)          0         
 1D)                                                             
                                                                 
 dropout_7 (Dropout)         (32, 28220, 64)           0         
                                                                 
 conv1d_17 (Conv1D)          (32, 28220, 1)            321       
                                                                 
=================================================================
Total params: 175,137
Trainable params: 175,137
Non-trainable params: 0
_________________________________________________________________
```

And the error message:

```
(2425, 28220)
75/76 [============================>.] - ETA: 9s - loss: 0.0283 - mse: 0.0283 
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
InvalidArgumentError                      Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-3-d30d9ac2067a> in <module>()
    105 #training the model
    106 print(train_data.shape)
--> 107 scda_train = model.fit(train_data, train_data, batch_size=batch_size,epochs=1,verbose=1, validation_data=(valid_data, valid_data))
    108 #print(train_data.shape)
    109 

1 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/execute.py in quick_execute(op_name, num_outputs, inputs, attrs, ctx, name)
     53     ctx.ensure_initialized()
     54     tensors = pywrap_tfe.TFE_Py_Execute(ctx._handle, device_name, op_name,
---> 55                                         inputs, attrs, num_outputs)
     56   except core._NotOkStatusException as e:
     57     if name is not None:

InvalidArgumentError: Graph execution error:

Detected at node 'sequential_2/dropout_4/dropout/Mul_1' defined at (most recent call last):
    File "/usr/lib/python3.7/runpy.py", line 193, in _run_module_as_main
      "__main__", mod_spec)
    File "/usr/lib/python3.7/runpy.py", line 85, in _run_code
      exec(code, run_globals)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/ipykernel_launcher.py", line 16, in <module>
      app.launch_new_instance()
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/traitlets/config/application.py", line 846, in launch_instance
      app.start()
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/ipykernel/kernelapp.py", line 499, in start
      self.io_loop.start()
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tornado/platform/asyncio.py", line 132, in start
      self.asyncio_loop.run_forever()
    File "/usr/lib/python3.7/asyncio/base_events.py", line 541, in run_forever
      self._run_once()
    File "/usr/lib/python3.7/asyncio/base_events.py", line 1786, in _run_once
      handle._run()
    File "/usr/lib/python3.7/asyncio/events.py", line 88, in _run
      self._context.run(self._callback, *self._args)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tornado/platform/asyncio.py", line 122, in _handle_events
      handler_func(fileobj, events)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tornado/stack_context.py", line 300, in null_wrapper
      return fn(*args, **kwargs)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/zmq/eventloop/zmqstream.py", line 577, in _handle_events
      self._handle_recv()
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/zmq/eventloop/zmqstream.py", line 606, in _handle_recv
      self._run_callback(callback, msg)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/zmq/eventloop/zmqstream.py", line 556, in _run_callback
      callback(*args, **kwargs)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tornado/stack_context.py", line 300, in null_wrapper
      return fn(*args, **kwargs)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/ipykernel/kernelbase.py", line 283, in dispatcher
      return self.dispatch_shell(stream, msg)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/ipykernel/kernelbase.py", line 233, in dispatch_shell
      handler(stream, idents, msg)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/ipykernel/kernelbase.py", line 399, in execute_request
      user_expressions, allow_stdin)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/ipykernel/ipkernel.py", line 208, in do_execute
      res = shell.run_cell(code, store_history=store_history, silent=silent)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/ipykernel/zmqshell.py", line 537, in run_cell
      return super(ZMQInteractiveShell, self).run_cell(*args, **kwargs)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.py", line 2718, in run_cell
      interactivity=interactivity, compiler=compiler, result=result)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.py", line 2822, in run_ast_nodes
      if self.run_code(code, result):
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.py", line 2882, in run_code
      exec(code_obj, self.user_global_ns, self.user_ns)
    File "<ipython-input-3-d30d9ac2067a>", line 107, in <module>
      scda_train = model.fit(train_data, train_data, batch_size=batch_size,epochs=1,verbose=1, validation_data=(valid_data, valid_data))
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/keras/utils/traceback_utils.py", line 64, in error_handler
      return fn(*args, **kwargs)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 1384, in fit
      tmp_logs = self.train_function(iterator)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 1021, in train_function
      return step_function(self, iterator)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 1010, in step_function
      outputs = model.distribute_strategy.run(run_step, args=(data,))
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 1000, in run_step
      outputs = model.train_step(data)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 859, in train_step
      y_pred = self(x, training=True)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/keras/utils/traceback_utils.py", line 64, in error_handler
      return fn(*args, **kwargs)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/keras/engine/base_layer.py", line 1096, in __call__
      outputs = call_fn(inputs, *args, **kwargs)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/keras/utils/traceback_utils.py", line 92, in error_handler
      return fn(*args, **kwargs)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/keras/engine/sequential.py", line 374, in call
      return super(Sequential, self).call(inputs, training=training, mask=mask)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/keras/engine/functional.py", line 452, in call
      inputs, training=training, mask=mask)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/keras/engine/functional.py", line 589, in _run_internal_graph
      outputs = node.layer(*args, **kwargs)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/keras/utils/traceback_utils.py", line 64, in error_handler
      return fn(*args, **kwargs)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/keras/engine/base_layer.py", line 1096, in __call__
      outputs = call_fn(inputs, *args, **kwargs)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/keras/utils/traceback_utils.py", line 92, in error_handler
      return fn(*args, **kwargs)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/keras/layers/core/dropout.py", line 112, in call
      lambda: tf.identity(inputs))
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/keras/utils/control_flow_util.py", line 106, in smart_cond
      pred, true_fn=true_fn, false_fn=false_fn, name=name)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/keras/layers/core/dropout.py", line 109, in dropped_inputs
      inputs, self.rate, noise_shape=self._get_noise_shape(inputs))
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/keras/backend.py", line 1941, in dropout
      seed=self.make_legacy_seed())
Node: 'sequential_2/dropout_4/dropout/Mul_1'
Incompatible shapes: [32,14110,32] vs. [25,14110,32]
     [[{{node sequential_2/dropout_4/dropout/Mul_1}}]] [Op:__inference_train_function_829911]
```

Comment: `model.fit(train_data, train_data, batch_size=batch_size,epochs=1,verbose=1, validation_data=(valid_data, valid_data))` You are passing the same dataset as `x` and `y` data. Since you're using `Dataset`, you only need to pass `x`, `Dataset` contains both features and labels. What is the shape of `train_data`? You may need to specify `x` specifically. You also are passing `valid_data` as `x` and `y`, you just need to pass it once since it's a `Dataset`.

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Thanks @Djinn, the shape of my training data is (2425, 28220) after splitting. So, i understood that I need to pass in valid_data once since it's a dataset to the validation_data argument, is that correct? Also, what do you mean by specify x. How can I do that?

Comment: @x1Hawkx24, as mentioned by Djinn, please change `model.fit(train_data, train_data, batch_size=batch_size,epochs=1,verbose=1, validation_data=(valid_data, valid_data))` to `model.fit(train_data, batch_size=batch_size,epochs=1,verbose=1, validation_data=valid_data)`. Thank you!

Comment: Thanks @Tfer3, I've tried that way. I got an error: ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all(). So i changed the argument validation_data=valid_data to validation_data=valid_data.any() and i got another error:  ValueError: Target data is missing. Your model was compiled with loss=mse, and therefore expects target data to be provided in `fit()`.

Comment: @x1Hawkx24, please try changing the batch size such that the number of training samples % batch size is equal to 0. I tried to replicate it on dummy data, after changing the batch size it is working fine, please find the gist [here](https://colab.sandbox.google.com/gist/synandi/cd061ce1350c73b6656f411aec1e8d8a/untitled163.ipynb#scrollTo=RDvLETawbCiP). Thank you!